# Redirect stdout to file and stderr to file and to screen

Tags: output, redirect

I am running valgrind to shake out bugs in my program.  Valgrind's memcheck prints to stderr.  What I want to do is a modification to this:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck ./a.out >output 2>grindout
```

But, I also want valgrind output to display on screen.  So program's output all goes to file.  Valgrind output is placed in grindout and displayed to screen.  How do I do so?

thanks.

Comment: `valgrind --tool=memcheck appname 2>&1 | tee valgrind.log` from http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tools/Valgrind

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? Did you find a solution? How are the existing answers?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the `tee` command. Unfortunately there's some trickery regarding redirecting stderr and stdout. The following should work:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck ./a.out 3>&1 2>&3 >output | tee grindout
```

This redirects standard output to `output`, moves standard error to a new file descriptor `3`, which points to stdout. `tee` takes this stdout-ified stderr and prints it both to your screen and to `gridnout`.

Comment: Thanks, but I want stderr to go to screen and to file.  But stdout to go to file and NOT to screen.

Comment: @Badministrator I've updated my answer to get that behavior. It's unexpectedly complicated (see [this Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342826/how-to-pipe-stderr-and-not-stdout)).

Answer (score 1):

Use tee for this, but you need to play some tricks with the stdout / stderr.

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck ./a.out 2>&1 > output | tee grindout
```

Explanation: `2>&1` sends stderr to stdout, and the regular stdout gets send to file `output`. The `tee` program passes on the stdin, but it also saves it to file `grindout`.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue. The problem was caused by buffering. You can read more about there here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
stdbuf -o0 valgrind -v --tool=memcheck stdbuf -o0 ./a.out  2>&1 | stdbuf -o0 tee grindout
```

the `'stdbuf -o0'` placed in front of each of the three programs that get executed causes them to turn off buffering.

The problem was never the the output wasn't being generated, nor was the problem that it wasn't going to the right place. The problem was that it wasn't getting there at the right time ( due to buffering )